# Kyverno: Validate ports are allowed only for k8s Service type LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, kyverno

I'm trying to achieve a specific case to be done with Kyverno, but can't find a good way to do that.
Also, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with Kyverno.

I want to allow assign the port 8000 only for Service type LoadBalancer for all namespaces. But allow assign all ports for Service type LoadBalancer in a specific namespace "ingress"

I tried to achieve this with validate and preconditions, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: allowed-ports-loadbalancer
spec:
  background: false
  validationFailureAction: enforce
rules:
  name: Validate ports are in the allowed range
  match:
    resources:
      kinds:
        - Service
  preconditions:
    all:
      - key: "{ { request.object.spec.type } }"
        operator: Equals
        value: "LoadBalancer"
  validate:
    pattern:
      spec:
        ports:
          - port: 8000
  exclude:
    resources:
      namespaces:
        - ingress
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, except in this case you want to invert the preconditions and the actual pattern because the first evaluation you want to make is on the ports, and the second is on the type. The below should take care of you.

```yaml
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: allowed-ports-loadbalancer
spec:
  background: false
  validationFailureAction: enforce
  rules:
  - name: Validate ports are in the allowed range
    match:
      any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
            - Service
    exclude:
      any:
      - resources:
          namespaces:
            - ingress
    preconditions:
      all:
        - key: 8000
          operator: AnyIn
          value: "{{ request.object.spec.ports[].port }}"
    validate:
      message: Port 8000 may only be set for LoadBalancer type Services outside the Namespace called `ingress`.
      pattern:
        spec:
          type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Hi Chip, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this also won't work. For some reason I could create the LB Service with port different from 8000 in any namespace.

also there's an error:
```EngineValidate "msg"="a condition failed in 'all' block" "kind"="Service" "name"="example-service" "namespace"="playground" "policy"="allowed-ports-loadbalancer" "rule"="Validate ports are in the allowed range" "condition"={"key":8000,"operator":"AnyIn","value":[9204]}```

Comment: actually the initial one worked for me after I upgraded the kyverno to the next minor version. From 2.5.2 to 2.5.5

Comment: I tested the policy I provided you on a 1.7 and (new) 1.8 release. If you say it's not working, can you supply a resource which isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the helm chart version and the kyverno version. So the deployed kyverno version is 1.7.5 in my cluster. 

Recent version of kyverno was v1.7.2-rc2 and mine or yours solution just didn't work as it was expected. Mine solution ignored the type of the service and denied any ports except 8000 to be deployed for any type of service, your solution just didn't work at all... I could create any type of service with any port in any namespace. 
I don't know, maybe it was buggy, but my solution works after I upgraded kyverno to v1.7.5